# How does the for loop intialization, condition and afterthought work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've reading the MDN docs, and I can truly say this is the first time in a while I have been baffled.

Refer to this code:

```js
for (
  let i = 0, getI = () => i, incrementI = () => i++;
  getI() < 3;
  incrementI()
) {
  console.log(i);
}
// Logs 0, 0, 0
```

I see the 1st iteration:

- for loop initializes `i` to `0`
- creates a closure over `i`
- creates a closure over `i++`
- calls `getI` function and returns `0`, executes the condition to continue, the loop executes `console.log(i)`

  - Is a new lexical scope created after `console.log(i)`? Does the initial `i` variable disappear?
  - does `getI` function get defined for each new iteration?
- calls `incrementI` and performs `i++`

  - Is a new `i` variable created, the previous `i` copied to the new `i` and then the new `i` incremented?
- next iteration begins

  - If a new `i` is generated with the new incremented value, why does `console.log(i)` still refer to the initial `i`, which is 0?

I read [the documentation in MDN about `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#using_for), however I could not find explanation of the behaviour shown in the code snippet. Why does it log `0`, `0`, `0` instead of `0`, `1`, `2`?

Comment: Is there something specific in [the specification text](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-for-statement) that you don't understand? If so, please clarify which part exactly so that a suitable answer can be provided. Currently, it seems like you are asking for a summarization of the spec...

Comment: @jsejcksn a lot of JS questions are essentially "summarization of the spec". Yet we routinely answer them anyway. Moreover, it's not like the spec is super easy to follow and accessible for just about anyone.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75936003/how-does-the-for-loop-intialization-condition-and-afterthought-work-in-javascri#comment133936179_75936003) @VLAZ While I agree with you, I also think many askers are either not aware that it exists, or [don't even attempt to read it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/438273).

Comment: @jsejcksn OP obviously has read the docs (the snippet is from the docs) but seemingly missed the part explaining the behavior of that snippet. I'm not sure especially beginners should be expected to read and understand the specifications beforehand.

Comment: Does [this analogy example](https://tsplay.dev/mL85Am) help you better conceptualize the behavior of the lexical bindings in the _initialization_? If so, I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75936003/how-does-the-for-loop-intialization-condition-and-afterthought-work-in-javascri?noredirect=1#comment133936770_75936003) @VLAZ That's part of why I included it in a comment now.

Comment: @jsejcksn while your analogy leads to the same results, it doesn't follow the specifications. Ie you are missing the `CreatePerIterationEnvironment` from the specs...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75936003/how-does-the-for-loop-intialization-condition-and-afterthought-work-in-javascri?noredirect=1#comment133937106_75936003) @derpirscher That's right: it's just a simplified analogy.

Comment: @jsejcksn But IMHO that simplification actually removes the crucial part, ie that there is a *newly declared* `i` in every iteration of the loop ... Because if it wasn't for that `CreatePerIterationEnvironment` the for loop would log `0, 1, 2` instead of `0,0,0` because all uses of `i` (ie also the `console.log(i)`) would actually refer to the very same `i`

Comment: @jsejcksn Your analogy does only part of this when it deconstructs the result from `initialization`  (ie separating the `i` in the loop's body from what is in the closure of `getI` and `incrementI`

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in this part of the docs

> The scoping effect of the initialization block can be understood as if the declaration happens within the loop body, but just happens to be accessible within the condition and afterthought parts. More precisely, let declarations are special-cased by for loops — if initialization is a let declaration, then every time, after the loop body is evaluated, the following happens:
>
> - A new lexical scope is created with new let-declared variables.
> - The binding values from the last iteration are used to re-initialize the new variables.
> - afterthought is evaluated in the new scope.

Ie, after each iteration of the loop a new `i` is declared with the value of the previous one. Then the `afterthought` is evaluated. But as in your case, `getI` and `incrementI` are closed over the *original* `i` this original `i` is incremented and checked (so the loop eventually stops) but the next call to `console.log` always uses the "new" `i`, which is initialized to `0` (ie the value of in the previous iteration *before* the afterthought was evaluated) and then never incremented.

Comment: So i understand that the original i is incremented in the closure incrementI and accessed in the closuure getI. Am i correct to understand that after the body of the for loop has been evaluated, a new i is created before the afterthought has been evaluated? And that this new i is initialized to 0 for the remaining 2nd and 3rd iterations? I don't quite understand how console.log(i) refers the value of i in the previous iteration before the afterthough is evaluated? Surely, the afterthought is unimportant and redundant otherwise it would affect the value of i in console.log(i)?

Answer (score -3):

I you want make that function work, just put initialization of `i` outside `for`.

```js
let i;
for (
  i = 0, getI = () => i, incrementI = () => i++;
  getI() < 3;
  incrementI()
) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: I want to understand it, not make the function work. I know how to make it work. But thank you.